# Meaning of “laughing string” in a Yeats poem

Tags: meaning, connotation, poetry, rhetorical-devices

Does anyone know the meaning of ‘laughing string’ in these lines by Yeats?

> Bred to a harder thing
>   Than Triumph, turn away
>   And like a **laughing string**
>   Whereon mad fingers play
>   Amid a place of stone,

The lines are from “[To a Friend Whose Work Has Come to Nothing](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/12882/to-a-friend-whose-work-has-come-to-nothing)”

Comment: This evokes gay fiddle music.

Comment: "string" refers to the string of a musical instrument. Does that make the metaphor more obvious?